# Pyspark label points aggregation

Tags: pyspark

I am performing a binary classification using LabeledPoint. I then attempt to sum() the number of labeled points with 1.0 to verify if the classification.

I have labelled an RDD as follows

```
lp_RDD = RDD.map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(1 if (flag in x[0]) else 0,x[1]))
```

I thought perhaps I could get a count of how many have been labelled with 1 using:

```
cnt = lp_RDD.map(lambda x: x[0]).sum()
```

But I get the following error :

```
'LabeledPoint' object does not support indexing
```

I have verified the labeled RDD as correct by printing the entire RDD and then doing a search for the string "LabeledPoint(1.0". I was simply wondering if there was a shortcut by trying to do a sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LabeledPoint has label value member which can be used to find the count or sum.Please try,

```
cnt = lp_RDD.map(lambda x: x.label).sum()
```